# shell script Remove specific words from variable in a comma separated string and remove of there is any comman before or after used sed or awk

Tags: linux, shell, variables, sed, scripting

I working on a shell script where it has 2 variables, 1st variable is the list of environments in a string and 2nd variable is the list of comma-separated values in a string, for example, we have **MAIN_ENV** and **ENV_TO_REMOVE_FROM_LIST** variables as below

```
MAIN_ENV="prod,dev,qa,qa1,qa2,stage,perf,production,perf1,UAT"
```

```
ENV_TO_REMOVE_FROM_LIST="prod,production,PROD,PRODUCTION"
```

Now, I have created the below script to remove **"prod,production,PROD,PRODUCTION"**  if the **MAIN_ENV** string variable contains **"ENV_TO_REMOVE_FROM_LIST"** values and which is now working

```
#!/bin/bash
MAIN_ENV="prod,dev,qa,qa1,qa2,stage,perf,production,perf1,UAT"
echo "Provided input Environments are: $MAIN_ENV"
ENV_TO_REMOVE_FROM_LIST="prod,production,PROD,PRODUCTION"
Final_Environments_List=$(echo $MAIN_ENV | sed s/"$ENV_TO_REMOVE_FROM_LIST"//)
echo "The Final List is: $Final_Environments_List"
```

I need out like below and sometimes I'm getting commas before are after the list

```
dev,qa,qa1,qa2,stage,perf,perf1,UAT
```

Can anyone please help me with this

Comment: Are you sure it's working, even when the envs to remove are not adjacent in the $MAIN_ENV?

Comment: @choroba, No exactly, if add only one value in "ENV_TO_REMOVE_FROM_LIST", it is removing the first iteam, can you help me to achieve this

Comment: Perhaps something like `sed -E 's/,production|production,|,prod|prod,//ig' file`?

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

MAIN_ENV="prod,dev,qa,qa1,qa2,stage,perf,production,perf1,UAT"
echo "Provided input Environments are: $MAIN_ENV"
ENV_TO_REMOVE_FROM_LIST="prod,production,PROD,PRODUCTION"

temp=$MAIN_ENV,$ENV_TO_REMOVE_FROM_LIST,$ENV_TO_REMOVE_FROM_LIST
temp=$(echo "${temp//,/$'\n'}" | sort | uniq -u)
Final_Environments_List=${temp//$'\n'/,}

echo "The Final List is: $Final_Environments_List"
```

`uniq -u` prints lines that only appear once in its  (sorted) input.

So by adding one copy of main env list and two copies of the remove list, only the main items that don't appear in remove list will be printed.

`sort` and `uniq` work on lines, not comma-delimited lists, so we use parameter substitution to convert between comma and newline.

---

An alternative method using Perl which retains the original order:

```
#!/bin/bash

MAIN_ENV="prod,dev,qa,qa1,qa2,stage,perf,production,perf1,UAT"
ENV_TO_REMOVE_FROM_LIST="prod,production,PROD,PRODUCTION"

Final_Environments_List=$(
  export MAIN_ENV ENV_TO_REMOVE_FROM_LIST;
  perl -E '
    $r{$_}++ for split /,/, $ENV{ENV_TO_REMOVE_FROM_LIST};
    say join ",", grep {!exists $r{$_}} split /,/, $ENV{MAIN_ENV};
  '
)
echo "The Final List is: $Final_Environments_List"
```

We export the variables so that Perl can access them directly.

The first line of the script populates a lookup table of the elements to remove.

The second line filters out elements that exist in the lookup table, then prints the remaining.